# Problemas com uma criação de Grid tkinter em python

Tags: python, tkinter, app, gui

Estou criando um app usando Python 3 e TKinter e estou tempo um problema de sobreposição dos widgets, não consigo enxergar o erro no código.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainFrame (ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,  container):
        super().__init__(container)

        divSearch = ttk.Frame(self)
        searchLabel = ttk.Label(divSearch,  text="Search:")
        searchLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="W")
        searchEntry = ttk.Entry(divSearch,  text="")
        searchEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="W")
        divSearch.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

        divSubjects = ttk.Frame(self)
        subjectsListBox = tk.Listbox(divSubjects)
        subjectsListBox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW", pady=5,  padx=5)
        subjectsCreateButton = ttk.Button(divSubjects, text="Create")
        subjectsCreateButton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="EW", pady=5, padx=5)
        subjectsEditButton = ttk.Button(divSubjects, text="Edit")
        subjectsEditButton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="EW", pady=5, padx=5)
        subjectsDeleteButton = ttk.Button(divSubjects, text="Delete")
        subjectsDeleteButton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="EW", pady=5, padx=5)
        divSubjects.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

        divNotes= ttk.Frame(self)

        divNotes.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="NSEW")
```

Resultado final
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se isso irá resolver o teu problema porem podes usar em vez do grid() podes usar a função pack() e dentro dela podes dizer onde queres que fiquem os teus conteiners
ex

```
self.nome=Label(self.frame,text='user:')
self.nome.pack(side=LEFT)
```

este codigo dentro do `__init__`
e em principio ficará consertado